# Why do I get this error message when working out the mean on R? And How do i fix it?

Tags: r, mean

So I am trying to work out the mean for a column on my dataset. When I use the code

```
mean(dataset$`name of column`)
```

it returns

> 'argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA'.

I have tried various ways to try and get around it but nothing will work

Initially the data had `NA` values, which I though was the issue, in it but I have removed them, by creating a dataframe, yet it still returns the same error message. I don't understand why this has happened as all data is numerical.

Sorry if this isn't well explained I'm pretty new to R.

Comment: It is because the column may not be numeric class.  check `class(dataset$yourcolumnname)`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you it has come back as a character rather than numeric which explains the problem.